# Will any ide warn me when I set "Optional<String> optional = null;"

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, ide, java-8

If I write something like this

```
java.util.Optional<String> optional = null;
```

or as a field (without init value, also not in constructors)

```
private Optional<String> optional;
```

or later in the code

```
optional = null;
```

I think I should get at least a warning. We had some unexpected NullpointerExceptions which were found very late because nobody expected the possibility to have a null-instance of an Optional (which was obviously a bug).

I tried Eclipse and IntelliJ and both didn't mention it. I also didn't found a plugin. Is there a reason why there isn't such a check? Or is it implemented somewhere?

Comment: there is no such check. Which makes optional another candidate for checking if they are null or not ....

Comment: Every up-to-date IDE should have support for the `@Nullable`, `@NonNull`, and `@NonNullByDefault` annotations… E.g., for Eclipse see http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-using_null_annotations.htm

Comment: All solutions are to avoid NPEs in general. Enabling these checks causes more then hundred warnings in our project. The comment with the Annotations is not uninteresting but I don't want to have Eclipse-specific annotations in my project and then it's still up to me to make sure annotation is placed correct.

Comment: @Marcel: you don’t need Eclipse-specific annotations. You can declare them within your project using any package and name you want and then configure Eclipse to use *your* annotations, though I’d recommend to keep the same simple names and only adapt the package so every developer will recognize these [commonly known annotations](https://www.google.de/search?q=NonNullByDefault+-eclipse). Of course *you* have to place these annotations at the right places, how would you expect compilers to ever understand what variables are allowed to be `null` and which not, if you don’t tell them?

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse, you can go to your project properties and then to Java Compiler --> Errors/Warnings, check `Enable project specific settings` and under `Potential programming problems` change the setting of `Potential null pointer access` to `Warning` or `Error` (as you'd like):

[image: Eclipse Errors/Warning --> Potential programming problems]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the warning for statement which may cause `NullPointer exception` in eclipse use [findbug plugin for eclipse](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/eclipse.html)

From [FindBugs Bug Descriptions](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html)

> **NP: Possible null pointer dereference (NP_NULL_ON_SOME_PATH)**
>   There is a branch of statement that, if executed, guarantees that a null value will be dereferenced, which would generate a NullPointerException when the code is executed. Of course, the problem might be that the branch or statement is infeasible and that the null pointer exception can't ever be executed; deciding that is beyond the ability of FindBugs.

Answer (score -4):

```
public final class Optional<T> {
....
}
```

As `Optional` is a class that inherits from `Object` (like every class in Java) it can be set to `null`. There is nothing wrong here.

But you should always be **aware** to set it to `Optional.empty()`, when you want to set it to an empty value.